# How do I create this element using Nokogiri builder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have an element in my XML but I am not sure how to get it generated in Nokogiri::XML::Builder.

```
<ns0:SearchCondition expressionLanguage='String'expressionType='PartyNumber'>31955854</ns0:SearchCondition>
```

I tried this:

```
def test_xml
    builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.root {
    xml.products {
      xml.widget {
        xml.id_ "10"
        xml.name "Awesome widget"
        xml.SearchCondition('expressionLanguage' => 'String', 'expressionType' => 'PartyNumber')
      }
    }
  }
end
puts builder.to_xml
```

This produces the following

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <root>
   <products>
     <widget>
       <id>10</id>
       <name>Awesome widget</name>
       <SearchCondition expressionLanguage="String" expressionType="PartyNumber"/>
    </widget>
 </products>
</root>
```

But I am not sure how I pass the value to the PartyNumber.

Comment: See http://sscce.org/. You need to supply a lot more context.

Comment: I just edited it.Let me know if you can help me. Thanks Ramya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking, but you can use the builder `text` method to create a text element inside another:

```
xml.SearchCondition('expressionLanguage' => 'String', 'expressionType' => 'PartyNumber') {
  xml.text "31955854"
}
```

You're not using the namespace in your example, but you don't mention that, so I guess that is not an issue.